# WAMP server on home network

Tags: wamp, dynamic-ip

I have a WAMP server running with NO-IP DUC. Host is plugged directly into my modem, then has it's Network Connection shared out to another connection which hosts the router.

Before, I had everything routed through the router and was able to get to the WAMP server via ports I had forwarded.

Now, with the WAMP server plugged directly into the modem, I can't get to the WAMP server from an outside connection.  I refreshed the NO-IP DUC settings so the IP address is up to date.  Is there something I'm going to need to do in order to get the WAMP server to see these settings?  Would the router in some way be hijacking those ports from the WAMP server?

Comment: Are you able to ping the server at all?

Comment: WAMP wasn't turned on.  I'm an idiot.